# Grails beforeInterceptor with 2 actions

Tags: grails, interceptor, grails-controller

Can we define 2 different actions in beforeInterceptor of a Grails controller? I have a controller with below beforeInterceptor:

```
def beforeInterceptor = [action:this.&debug]

def trimParams() {
    params?.each { it = it.toString().trim() }
}
def debug() {
    log.info("${actionUri} with params ${params}")
}
```

How can I add the 'trimParams' action to interceptor along with 'debug' action? I do not know the exact syntax of this. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you defining a separate action for the interceptor:

```
def beforeInterceptor = [action:this.&doBeforeStuff]

def doBeforeStuff() {
    trimParams(params)
    debug(params)
}

def trimParams() {
    params?.each { it = it.toString().trim() }
}
def debug() {
    log.info("${actionUri} with params ${params}")
}
```

I have not tried it, but it might help.